# Do the additional jumps from accessories stack

Tags: terraria

Since the Terraria 1.2 update, there are several accessories which can provide additional jumps, such as the cloud in a bottle, sandstorm in a bottle, and blizzard in a bottle. How do these items stack? Do the jumps combine into one, does one take priority over the rest, or do you get multiple different jumps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Cloud in a Bottle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cloud_in_a_Bottle) page:

> This item can stack with the [Blizzard in a Bottle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blizzard_in_a_Bottle), and [Sandstorm in a Bottle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sandstorm_in_a_Bottle), for a triple, or even quadruple jump.

There are, however, some slight differences for the Blizzard and Sandstorm.

> Unlike the Cloud in a Bottle, the **Blizzard in a Bottle** possesses an 'air drag' double jump feature which works slightly similarly to a pair of Rocket Boots and/or Wings. The player can gain more hang time and control with their jump for a short period of time by holding down the jump button. However, when the double jump is exhausted and the player does not 'drag' their jump, the player cannot continue the 'air drag' as they descend. Blizzard in a Bottle can be found in Ice Chests, in the Ice Underground Underground Biome.
>
> The **Sandstorm in a Bottle** is very similar to the Cloud in a Bottle, but instead of a cloud beneath your feet, a sand jet appears and the character spins as they ascend on that jet. Due to this, the Sandstorm in a Bottle allows for jumps that are nearly twice as high as the Cloud in a Bottle.

Furthermore, each of these can be made into its own distinct Cloud/Blizzard/Sandstorm in a Balloon.  These three balloons can then be combined into the [Bundle of Balloons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bundle_of_Balloons) which condenses your quadruple jump into a single item.

Comment: Good to see the wiki finally getting updated. Thanks O.R. Could you expand a bit on what order the jumps come in?

Comment: @Fambida I'd be glad to once I get all three :D

Comment: I finished my balloon bundle, and so far the order is sandstorm, blizzard, cloud, rocket, magic carpet. Not sure about wings yet since my server folks and I haven't gone hardmode yet. Sandstorm is a longer jump than blizzard, which is longer than cloud.